# ConcurrentHashMap is empty after serialization

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to serialize the ServletState which has a private static ConcurrentHashMap variable with 10 items added.  When I serialize out and then read in again, I can see all the other variables are ok, except for ConcurrentHashMap which is now empty.  Looking at the ser file I can't see anything for ConcurrentHashMap, so I assume the setup for serialize is missing something and it fails without any exception.

```
public class ServletState implements java.io.Serializable
{
@Serial
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final String serialFileName = "ServletState.ser";

private static File servletDataPath = new File(YamlReader.getConfig().getApp().getServletDataPath() + serialFileName);

private static boolean initializeClass = false;

/**
 * This hold the status of each activity you can do
 */
private static ConcurrentHashMap<ToolType, ExecuteStatus> servletState = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
public ServletState()
    {
    }
    }

ToolType is a enum class:  
public enum ToolType
{
    @JsonProperty("deploy")
    DEPLOY_SERVICES("deployServices"),
ect.
}
```

Status class

```
/**
 * This class holds the status states.
 */
public enum Status
{
    /**
     * The activity setup has been completed
     */
    @JsonProperty("Configured")
    CONFIGURED,
     etc.
```

ExecuteStatus is a class setup for seriation and uses 2 more enum classes ToolType and Status:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class ExecuteStatus implements Serializable
{
@Serial
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  


    /**
     * What you did
     */
    private final ToolType toolType;

    /**
     * Date when you did it. Format MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss or N/A
     */
    private final String lastExecuted;

    /**
     * Did it work or not?
     */
    private final Status status;

    public ExecuteStatus(ToolType toolType, Date lastExecuted, Status status) {
    }
}
```

There are no other classes being used in these 3 classes beyond String, so it should serialize without any problems.  No exceptions are being thrown on the write out to file or reading in from file.  So why is the structure failing to serialize this container?

Comment: `static` variables are not included in a serialization of an instance.  So if you are serializing a `ServletState` instance or something that refers to a `ServletState` instance, then the serialization won't include your `servletState` map.   If this doesn't answer your question, you need to tell us precisely what you are serializing and show us the code that does it or triggers it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, all the static variables are really not being serialized out.  I am now just serializing out the static container directly and do try to serialize out the class since that's all I wanted saved.  If I wanted everything in the class, I would have to make a custom serialization function and write out each static variable one at a time to the ser file.